# How to configure Ruby on Rails app to use Buddhist calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

In Buddhist Era calendar it's already 2555 year. What is the easiest way to make Date.current show 2555 instead of 2012?

UPDATE

I've found solution for this particular task. It can be easily implemented with just standard rails i18n.

cat config/locales/th.rb

```
{
  th: {
    date: {
      formats: {
        default: lambda { |date, _| "%d.%m.#{date.year + 543}" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then just use I18n.l method:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :032 > I18n.l(Date.current)
 => "30.10.2555"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for.

https://github.com/ai/r18n

```
R18n.set('th')
R18n.l Time.now, :full #=> "1 พฤศจิกายน, 2554 12:00"
```

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that it fails if any translation missing (I18n::MissingTranslationData) exists :(

Comment: in which case you probably haven't installed r18n correctly. add `gem 'r18n-rails'` to your gemfile.\